# SLA for web application with a single time value

Tags: api, time, google-chrome-devtools, metrics, selenium-chromedriver

I am establishing the SLA for my web application.  To do this I want a rollup of the speed of the entire page load -- a single value reported in milliseconds (ms).

I need to be able to have this value programmatically (from a command-line or script - not embedded in a UI)

Then I will push this single value into an existing metrics engine for reporting / graphing (statsd or collectd for those metrics people)

I would like the value to be representative for how a client (Chrome, Firefox) would perform.   Though I am less interested in the rendering time of the client and more interested in the total response time: from the initial call through the nested app calls -- but a value including rendering time would be fine.

I believe modern clients have API's which will return an aggregated value -- but I cannot find a API which will provide a rollup value for the speed of the entire page-load.

~~~

Background:  When a client browser performs an http get -- the server responds with a framework containing other http gets, which the client browser must then send off for.
The response time value I am looking for is from the initial client browser request through all the nested and embedded gets.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you looked into Navigation Timing API? www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/